# How to tunnel traffic from localhost:port1 to remotehost2:port3 through a middle host remotehost3 which can be accessed only through SSH?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'd like to execute a tunnel on my localhost so all the traffic on a host ends up on a remotehost through a middle hop that can only accessed by ssh

```
LOCALHOST ________ MIDDLEHOST_______________ REMOTEHOST
  portX             port 22                     portX
   |                                                 
   |
$> tunnel creation

I have credentials to MIDDLEHOST machine
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear exactly what's being tunneled where. Is the connection from middlehost to remotehost an SSH connection (like the one between localhost and middlehost), or a native (non-tunneled) TCP connection? Also, what do you mean by "all the traffic on a host"?

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `~/.ssh/config`, and add a stanza like:

```
Host destinationhost
    ProxyJump middlehost
```

Now whenever you type `ssh destinationhost`, ssh will open an ssh connection to `middlehost`, create a tunnel through it, and then open a *second* ssh connection through that tunnel to `destinationhost`. Any port forwards that you set up through `-L` or `-R` or whatnot will apply to that second connection, *not* the first.